# Does this question require double u-substitution?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

$$\int_0^1\frac1{(1+\sqrt x)^4}\,dx$$
The first substitution I thought to do was $u=\sqrt x$ and $du=\frac 12x^{-1/2}\,dx$. So what I have my integral change into is
$$\int_0^1\frac1{(1+\sqrt u)^4}\,du$$ 
I am not sure how to use the $du$ and where to go from there.

Comment: $x=u^2\implies dx=2udu$

Comment: $du= \frac 12x^\frac {-1}{2} dx=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2u}dx$ so $dx=2u~du$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution was performed wrongly. I would suggest using $u=1+\sqrt x$ with $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac1{2\sqrt x}$:
$$=\int_1^2\frac{2(u-1)}{u^4}\,du$$
$$=2\int_1^2\left(\frac1{u^3}-\frac1{u^4}\right)\,du$$
$$=2\left[-\frac1{2u^2}+\frac1{3u^3}\right]_1^2$$
$$=2\left(-\frac18+\frac1{24}+\frac12-\frac13\right)=\frac16$$
So only a *single* substitution is required, in fact.

Comment: nice answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $x=u^2$. Then, $dx=2udu$.

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^4}dx=\int_0^1\frac{2u}{(1+u)^4}du$$

Comment: How do you know that 2udu goes on top?

Comment: Because you are replacing $dx$ by $2udu$

Comment: Then why do you add du again at the end?

Comment: @Katelyn A typo sorry. fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Or:
$$1+\sqrt{x}=u \Rightarrow x=(u-1)^2 \Rightarrow dx=2(u-1)du.$$
$$\int_1^2 \frac{2(u-1)du}{u^4}=\int_1^2 2u^{-3}du -\int_1^2 2u^{-4}du=-u^{-2}|_1^2+\frac23u^{-3}|_1^2=...$$